# App not allowing to install in supported devices

Tags: android, android-manifest

I uploaded app in play store,and in play store it says required android is 4.0 and up,and one of my friend want to install and his device has android version 4.4.2 and it shows device is not compatible following is my manifest file,still not getting what is the issue..

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="mypackagename"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses- permission>  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
     </compatible-screens>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/headings"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/headings" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        >

    </activity>
    <activity android:name="FirstLoginPage"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        >
     <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
               </activity>
               </application>
           </manifest>
```

Comment: i guess his device is xxhdpi.. all high end phones like nexus ,samsung are xxhdpi devices .. check with the resolution.. You have not mentioned supporting xxhdpi devices

Comment: but what about api level..?did i set that right?

Comment: you have set the api right but you have mentioned screen resolution as well . So it also looks for the devices with particular resolution.

Comment: you have mentioned targetSdkVersion. So there is no upper limit for the sdk version . its proper.. :)

Comment: should i need to remove targetversion? and one of my friedn who has samsung grand 2 which screen size is 720x1280 and he is able to install my app.and he is also having 4.4.2 version..so i am confuse

Comment: 720x1280 comes under xhdpi category

Comment: ok sony experia c3 also having same screen size and same version of samsung grand 2..but in sony it says device not compatible

Comment: its probably comes under large category

Comment: but i already set xhdpi and isnt it large?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add screen support for `large` also:

```
<!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
```

**UPDATE:** 
Sony Xperia C3 has 5.5 screen size which comes under "large" screen category so above code will work. Add support for large screen size devices also.

Read this for more details: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#overview

Comment: API levels are fine because your friends device has API level 19 (4.4.2). It is right

Comment: then why he is not able to install?

Comment: @malis, try above which i mentioned then hopefully it will work. May it is not working because your friend's device screen resolution is not mentioned in your app manifest.xml. Add above code and then check

Comment: ok sony experia c3 also having same screen size and same version of samsung grand 2..but in sony it says device not compatible

Comment: @malis, Xperia C3 has large screen size category (5.5) so add above code it will work. It does not comes under normal screen size category.

Comment: Samsung grand 2 has 5.2 screen which also comes under large category. Read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#overview

Comment: ok i will try as per your answer..but can you edit full compatible screen tag? so that i can figure out wihtout any mistakes..i vote up

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75082/discussion-between-malis-and-vicjordan).

Comment: i tried with your answer and it says  Error: String types not allowed (at 'screenDensity' with value 'xxhdpi').

Comment: @malis, sorry for late reply. I just checked that xxhdpi is not allowed at all in screenDensity. Reason i dont know. I have edited my answer. Now it will definitely work. Just add support for large screen size

Comment: yes but pager is not working properly so i thought may be you can tell about that

Comment: now you can add your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29627186/java-lang-indexoutofboundsexception-invalid-index-7-size-is-7

Comment: May I know the reason, why someone has down voted this answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
  <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" 

        />
```

try this if you want support all screens.. This code involves tablet also .
[refer this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html) to exclude tablets

Comment: and after add supports-screen do i need to remove compatible screen tag from my manifest?

Comment: yeah correct .. you need to remove the rest all  compatible screen tag

Comment: after this upload your apk .. while uploading it shows number of compatible devices.. the number would be increased

Comment: i too had same issue regarding compatible devices.. above code solved the issue.. :)

Comment: can you help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29816813/how-to-get-items-from-autocompletetextview-to-autocompletetextivew