# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 7, size is 7

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am trying to implement view pager,in my view pager images comes from server,I am able to display and scroll but when i reach at last image it shows error and app got crash,following is my snippet code

```
   public class Test_Pager extends Activity{


private String strtd;
String[] imgStr;
ImageView imageView;
ArrayList<String> userImgArrayList;
String[] myURLs;


/*country list*/
JSONArray country_list=null;
private ServiceHandler sh;
private String jsonStr;
private JSONObject jsonObj;
private String user_img;
private String user_pro;
private static String PROFILE_VIEW_URL = "";

private static final String USER_IMG="product_images";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_pagerss);

    userImgArrayList = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("user_images");
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
       ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
       viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

     imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);


     PROFILE_VIEW_URL="";
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(PROFILE_VIEW_URL, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

     try {
         jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);


             /*proview_business = jsonObj.getString(PROFILE_VIEW_BUSINESS);
             proview_subcat = jsonObj.getString(PROFILE_VIEW_SUB_CATAGORY);
             proview_mainpro = jsonObj.getString(PROFILE_VIEW_MAINPRODUCTS);
             proview_expr = jsonObj.getString(PROFILE_VIEW_EXPERIENCE);
             proview_cmpname = jsonObj.getString(PROFILE_VIEW_COMPANYNAME);
             proview_website = jsonObj.getString(PROFILE_VIEW_WEBSITE);*/

            // user_img=jsonObj.getString(USER_IMG);



            user_img=jsonObj.getString(USER_IMG);
            user_img = "";
            userImgArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();//declare userImgArrayList globally like ArrayList<String> userImgArrayList;
            JSONArray picarray = jsonObj.getJSONArray(USER_IMG);
            for(int i=0;i< picarray.length();i++)
            {
                user_img = picarray.getString(i);
                userImgArrayList.add(user_img);
                Log.d("mylog", "curent  pro pic  = " + user_img);
            }


     } catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

}
public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
     Context context;
      ImageAdapter(Context context)
     {
     this.context=context;
     }
      @Override
      public int getCount() {
      return USER_IMG.length();
      }

      @Override
        public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
             ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
        }
     @Override
     public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
     return view == ((ImageView) object);
     }

     @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
            int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
                    R.dimen.activity_horizontal_margin);
            imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
            //imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            //Picasso.with(context).load(userImgArrayList.get(position)).into(imageView);
            Picasso.with(context).load(userImgArrayList.get(position)).resize(200, 200) .into(imageView);

            /*for(int i=0; i<myURLs.length;i++)
            { 

                try {
                    url = new URL(myURLs[i]);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                 imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            }
            */
            // imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imgStr[position]));
            ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
            return imageView;
        }
     }

  }
```

Myxml

```
        <RelativeLayout 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:background="@android:color/white"
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">







       <ScrollView 
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lnr"
            android:fillViewport="true"

                >

           <LinearLayout 
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
                 >
          <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
      android:id="@+id/view_pager"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ImageView android:id="@+id/full_image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/></LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/secondpart"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    >
      <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:shrinkColumns="*"  android:stretchColumns="*" >
       <TableRow
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:text="Product Name"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            />


        <TextView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/txtageprofile"

            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            /></TableRow>
        <TableRow
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        >
         <TextView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:text="Code"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            />


        <TextView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"

            android:id="@+id/txtheightprofile"

          android:textColor="@android:color/black"
          android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            /></TableRow>
         <TableRow
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        >
         <TextView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:text="Purchase Rate"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            />


        <TextView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"

            android:id="@+id/txtmrgprofile"

            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            /></TableRow>
          <TableRow
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp">
         <TextView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:text="Weight"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            />

         <TextView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"

            android:id="@+id/txtworkingprofile"

            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            /></TableRow>
           <TableRow
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        >
         <TextView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:text="Sales Rate"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            />

         <TextView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/txtplaceprofile"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            /></TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
           <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/secondpart"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    >
            <TextView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"

            android:id="@+id/txteatprofile"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            />
            </LinearLayout>


      </LinearLayout>
      </ScrollView>
      </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: USER_IMG.length() will return the string length, instead use image array for fetching the count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`USER_IMG.length();` returns the length of the `String` (the number of chars of "product_images"). You should return the size of the data set instead. Change

```
 @Override
 public int getCount() {
      return USER_IMG.length();
 }
```

to

```
 @Override
 public int getCount() {
      if (userImgArrayList == null) {
         return 0;
      } 
      return userImgArrayList.size();
 }
```

Comment: it shows java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! Expected adapter item count: 0, found: 7 Pager id: com.example.tab_with_list:id/view_pager Pager class: class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager Problematic adapter: class com.example.tab_with_list.Test_Pager$ImageAdapter

Comment: call `viewPager.notifyDataSetChanged();` **after** the for loop that fills up `userImgArrayList`

Comment: it says The method notifyDataSetChanged() is undefined for the type ViewPager...i added after for loop..for(int i=0;i< picarray.length();i++)
                {
                    user_img = picarray.getString(i);
                    userImgArrayList.add(user_img);
                    Log.d("mylog", "curent  pro pic  = " + user_img);
                }
                viewPager.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: it's `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: why view pager is taking full screen?my other data is not showing

Comment: ViewPager shows only one page at time. To display the others you have to swipe on the right

Comment: you just misunderstood me..I know i need to swipe right..other data means my textview's which i set..

Comment: your adapter has **only** imageviews

Comment: can you hellp? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29646867/how-to-add-viewpagerindicator

Answer (score 0):

change your getcount() method to

```
@Override
  public int getCount() {
    int count =0
    if (userImgArrayList != null) {
     count=userImgArrayList.size();
  }
  return count;
```

}

And also add `notifyDataSetChanged` after filling the arraylist like this..

```
 for(int i=0;i< picarray.length();i++)
            {
                user_img = picarray.getString(i);
                userImgArrayList.add(user_img);
                Log.d("mylog", "curent  pro pic  = " + user_img);
            }
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Answer (score 0):

replace,

`Picasso.with(context).load(userImgArrayList.get(position)).resize(200, 200) .into(imageView);`

with,

```
try{Picasso.with(context).load(userImgArrayList.get(position)).resize(200, 200) .into(imageView);}catch(Exception e){

e.printStackTrace();}
```